# for not indexing correctly while foreach is working

Tags: c#, for-loop, indexing

I have been using an array of this class for a while and ive been using foreach but when I try to access it using a for loop (actually indexing) its going out of the array. Any help?

-Working-

```
[TestMethod]
public void Scorer_FullHouse_ReturningZero()
{
    SetOfDice[] diceRolls = new SetOfDice[] {
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {1,1,2,2,3}),
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {3,5,3,4,3}),
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {7,7,7,7,7})
    };

    foreach (SetOfDice roll in diceRolls)
    {
        int score = scorer.getScore(roll, category);
            Assert.AreEqual(score, 0);
    }
}
```

-Not Working-

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Scorer_ThreeOfAKind_Success()
{
    SetOfDice[] diceRolls = new SetOfDice[] {
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {1,2,1,4,1}),
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {1,7,6,5,2}),
        new SetOfDice(new int[] {8,8,8,8,8})
    };

    int[] expectedResults = new int[] {
        9,
        0,
        40
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < expectedResults.Length; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults[i], scorer.getScore(diceRolls[i], GameVariables.Category.ThreeOfAKind));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the stack trace - are you sure the error isn't coming from `scorer.getScore`?

Comment: Side note:  I'm not sure what the game is, but in Yahtzee, 5 of a kind _can_ be considered a "full house"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is somewhere else. But you can make sure of it by looking into the stack trace. Also you can change your for loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(expectedResults.Length,diceRolls.length) ; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults[i], scorer.getScore(diceRolls[i], GameVariables.Category.ThreeOfAKind));
    }
```

Now if you execute it with this for loop and you are still having the `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`then you know it is coming from something else.

Comment: It was found elsewhere! Thanks.